How to organize a Python project when migrating from sql queries to API requests?
I am working on a project that used to fetch all the required data from an external DB. Soon the DB won't be accesable anymore and is going to be replaced by endpoints.
Assuming that I have a structure like
project_root/
├── sql/
│   ├── query1.sql
│   ├── query2.sql
│   └── ...
├── main.py
└── ...

Where main has the function that calls the different query modules. How should I name the new structure? Like this?
project_root/
├── requests/
│   ├── request1.py
│   ├── request2.py
│   └── ...
├── main.py
└── ...


replaced by endpoints - You mean the database interaction is now inside the endpoints? What framework do you use for building your API?

Yes, now is inside the endpoints. I am using FastAPI

Let's assume you have users and items in your project.
Here I group the project by entities (routes, repositories, controllers, etc.), but it can be also grouped by domains (users, items) which is also fine.
project_root/
├── routes/  # Contains your endpoints, should not contain any business logic.
│   ├── user.py
│   ├── item.py
│   └── ...
├── clients/  # Contains db client, s3 client, any client to interact with other services etc.
│   ├── db_client.py
│   └── ...
├── models/  # Contains db models that should reflect the database structure. Commonly ORM is used e.g. SQLAlchemy. The result of your queries should be converted to the models.
│   ├── user.py
│   ├── item.py
│   └── ...
├── schemas/  # Contains pydantic models: schemas / DTOs
│   ├── user.py
│   ├── item.py
│   └── ...
├── repositories/  # The only place containing database queries. Ideally models should be returned from repository methods.
│   ├── user.py
│   ├── item.py
│   └── ...
├── controllers/  # Contains business logic: take something from client, repository, do something, prepare API answer.
│   ├── user.py
│   ├── item.py
│   └── ...
├── main.py
└── ...

Differences between models and schemas as well as an example of entities I mentioned you can find in my previous answer.
